# How to retrieve response from JSON to simple type

Tags: jquery, json

I have problem to retrieve an int value from a JSON response. Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult GetCartCount()
{
    int caounofcart = shoppingCartManager.GetCartItemsCount();
    return Json(new { name = caounofcart });
}
```

```js
function updateQuantity() { 
    // code...
    $("#cartbox").text(updatecart);   // here is span element
    // code...
}

function updatecart() {
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetCartCount", "Cart")", function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $each(data, function (key, val) {
            items.push(val);
        })
        $("#cartbox").text(items[0]);
        return items[0];
    });
};
```

I want to change text content in the `span` element through the JSON response. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you cannot achieve this using the logic you specify as the AJAX request is asynchronous. This means that the `updatecart()` function will have exited long before any data is returned from the request, so no value will be provided to `text()`.

Secondly, you only return a single integer value in the JSON response so you can simply use `data.name` to get the returned count.

With those issues in mind, try this:

```
function updateQuantity(){ 
    // code...
    updateCart();
    // code...
}

function updateCart() {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCartCount", "Cart")', function(data) {
        $('#cartbox').text(data.name);
    });
}
```